# Asp.Net Core Web API Patch Id Is Always NULL

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-3.1, http-patch

I have a asp.net core web api with an endpoint using PATCH. Need to update a single field of a record. I have the endpoint setup to accept the id of the record along a Json Patch Document body.

Here is how my endpoint is currently setup. I just have enough code to check that I can find a matching id which is not working as expected.

```
[HttpPatch("{id}")]
    public IActionResult updateDescription( [FromRoute] string reportId, [FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<Reports> patchEntity)
    {

        //reportId is null... not showing the id being passed in the api call
        if (patchEntity == null)
        {
            return Ok("body is null");
        }
     

        var entity = _context.Reports.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ReportId == reportId);

        if (entity == null)
        {
            return Ok(reportId + " Why is entity null!");
        }

        //patchEntity.ApplyTo(entity, ModelState);

        return Ok(entity + " found!");
    }
```

When I call the api passing the Id the report ID parameter shows null.

[report ID parameter shows null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbDU9.jpg)

API call: http://localhost:4200/api/updateDesc/A88FCD08-38A3-48BB-8E64-61057B3C0B1F
I am using postman and the JSON body is being sent and read correctly by the API endpoint.
[body return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2rBQ.jpg)

What am I missing that is causing the ID from the route to not be assigned to the reportID parameter?

I also tried a slight different endpoint as well with the same results

```
[HttpPatch("{id}")]
    public IActionResult updateDescription(string reportId, [FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<Reports> patchEntity)
    {

        //reportId is null... not showing the id being passed in the api call
        if (patchEntity == null)
        {
            return Ok("body is null");
        }
     

        var entity = _context.Reports.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ReportId == reportId);

        if (entity == null)
        {
            return Ok(reportId + " Why is entity null!");
        }

        //patchEntity.ApplyTo(entity, ModelState);

        return Ok(entity + " found!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try now

```
[HttpPatch("{reportId}")]
    public IActionResult updateDescription( [FromRoute] string reportId, [FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<Reports> patchEntity)
    {
```